# How do I provide tags for my collectionView UITextFields programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Thanks in advance for reading. Newbie here.

I have a `collectionView`. In it, I am using a custom `collectionViewCell` to repeat my custom `cell`. Each cell consists of 2 `UILabels` and 1 `UITextfield`.

I want to enter information in all `textfields` and once I click my calculate `button` I want to record the data. I'm trying to assign tags with `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

my code is as follows

```
var inputNamesArray = ["Ice Cream", "Number of Scoops", "Main Dish", "Side Dish"]

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? inputCell else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let inputLabels = inputNamesArray[indexPath.row]
    let inputUnits = unitArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.inputLabel.text = inputLabels
    cell.inputText.tag = inputLabels.count //this isn't working
    cell.inputUnitLabel.text = inputUnits  
   // cell.inputText.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    return cell
}
```

`inputLabel` `inputText` and `inputUnitLabel` are the names of the labels and textfields.

Does anybody know how to give tags to my `uitextfield` in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method?

I also read on the Apple documentation it is possible to use `enum` but I really didn't understand how.

Any help, using any method to `give tags to my (reusable cell) UITextfields so that I can store and use the data` would be so helpful! Thanks so much!!

p.s. the reason I know my above code is not working, is because i am using

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.count)
}
```

and it prints out tags for the labels, but no tags when i click on the textfields. Also I have tried removing the

```
cell.inputText.tag = inputLabels.count
```

but it still doesn't return any tags for the `textfields`.

p.s.2 in case you were interested, this is the code for my calculate button, if there is anything I can do there, let me know:)

```
   @objc func calculateButtonActions() {
    print("calculate tap worked")
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let resultsPage = ResultsPageController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsPage, animated: true)
}
```

and this declaration in ViewDidLoad()

```
ViewDidLoad() {
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 550, width:     view.frame.width, height: 100))
    button.setTitle("Calculate", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(calculateButtonActions), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

}

THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Replace `cell.inputText.tag = inputLabels.count` with this `cell.inputText.tag = indexPath .row`

Comment: Thanks SO much ! I am using this new declaration, but how do i call each specific textfield now, to be able to use their data? because cell is only declared inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath ` Thanks so much!

Comment: so you want to get tapped textfield data as well right?

Comment: yes exactly, I know how to do it for textfields I have specifically named, this is my code for those: `let resultAddressLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel() return label }()` and then `var address =  resultAddressLabel.text` . but in the case above (of repeatable cells) i don't know how to do it. or exactly where to declare it. Thanks so much for the help again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForItemAt` delegate set you `cell.inputText.delegate = self`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell // REPLACE YOUR CELL NAME WITH CollectionViewCell

        cell.inputText.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

Now you can get tapped textview data by using `textViewDidBeginEditing` delegate like below.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate { // REPLACE ViewController with Your ViewController Name
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        var cell: CollectionViewCell?
        cell = textView.superview?.superview as? CollectionViewCell
        print(cell?.txtVW.text as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kuldeep! I still can't retrieve the values for each textfield. this is my code: `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? inputCell else { // inputCell is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell
            fatalError()
        }
        cell.inputText.delegate = (self as? UITextFieldDelegate)`

Comment: And I'm declaring `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            var cell: inputCell?
            cell = textField.superview?.superview as? inputCell
            print(cell?.inputText.text as Any)
        }` because I need to retrieve the information when all inputting is done (there are 6 cells total. My problem is still that I need to retrieve the information entered by the user, in an orderly fashion (maybe an array?) so that I can USE those values for calculations. This is for a very extensive calculator I am making. Thanks so much, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: by the way I tried using the extension but I got an error that said that `DECLARATION is only valid at file scope` so I guess I can't add extension inside of view controller?

Comment: @valeriana, Here is demo link in which There's textView as well as TextField in CollectionView and full code. It will hep you. https://www.dropbox.com/s/972qlhtn27bat2z/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: hi kuldeep! thanks so much! I tried opening it, but it was only a file with a button on the storyboard and it wasn't connected to any code :(

Comment: @valeriana, sorry it was my mistake, there's another test demo Here is the new link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/q254bpnjxe2eu1d/temp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks so much! I did check the code and it was very helpful!

Comment: @valeriana, if this answer helpful to you, up vote it.

Comment: Hi kuldeep, it was! Thanks so much, I can accept answers but I can’t upvote yet, I need more rep points for that, sorry. But thanks so much!

Comment: @valeriana, okay

Comment: I’ll definitely upvote as soon as I get the points I need. Thanks again so much!

Comment: I just got enough rep points to upvote answers! Thanks again so much for your help and for your patience. :)